# What is the difference between using LASTDATE and MAX to get the last date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

What is the difference between using LASTDATE and MAX to get the last date value.

For example:

LASTDATE ( DateTable[Date]) )

vs

MAX ( DateTable[Date]) )

Comment: here is a detailed article about it https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-the-difference-between-lastdate-and-max-in-dax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of the return value. `LASTDATE` returns a table with one row and one column.

Therefore, use cases are different. You use max if you want to display max date or use it as a comparison criterion, whereas lastdate can be used in filter part of CALCULATE, as you pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Ok so LASTDATE is usefull for example as filter to CALCULATE. Where as max cannot be used as filter to CALCULATE.